# Laravel Model boot->deleted chaining on boot method not working

Tags: php, laravel

Asking if this is possible or not.

Steps to produce:

1. In AController, delete a record of AModel.
2. In AModel, create a method to link to BModel using hasMany
3. Still in AModel, add a boot method to delete all related BModel of AModel
4. In BModel, create a method to link to CModel using hasMany
5. Still in BModel, add a boot method to delete all related CModel of BModel

and so on.

If I delete AModel, I can delete all related BModel(s) but unable to delete the CModel(s) related to the deleted BModel(s).

If I delete BModel, I can delete all releted CModel(s) but unable to delete the DModel(s) related to the deleted CModel(s).

etc.

AController.php

```
public function deleteA(Request $request)
{
  ...
  $aModel = AModel::where('id', $request->id)->first();
  $aModel->delete();
  ...
}
```

AModel.php

```
public function hasManyBModels()
{
  return $this->hasMany(BModel::class, 'a_id', 'id');
}

public static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  static::deleted(function ($bModel) {
    $bModel->hasManyBModels()->delete();
  });
}
```

BModel.php

```
public function hasManyCModels()
{
  return $this->hasMany(CModel::class, 'b_id', 'id');
}

public static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  static::deleted(function ($cModels) {
    $cModels->hasManyCModels()->delete();
  });
}
```

Comment: This can probably be done most effectively with `onDeleteCascade()` in your table migrations, however this would depend on you not using soft deletes for any parents.

Comment: Yes I did consider to use onDeleteCascade for efficiency but not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the code inside the boot method:

AModel.php

```
public static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  static::deleted(function ($aModels) {
    $aModels->hasManyBModels->each->delete();
  });
}
```

With the code above, when AModel data is deleted, all related BModel data is also deleted and at the same time, CModel related to the deleted BModel is also deleted.

Though this does answer what I asked earlier, it is not an efficient since it will execute multiple queries to perform the delete.

For example, deleting 1 AModel will delete 1k related BModel and 1k related CModel on each BModel.

This will take too many queries. Will search on another method for efficiency.

(2 * 1000 BModels「select and update query」) * (2 * 1000 CModels「select and update query」)